# Как обработать событие показа ( Show() ) окна WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Открываю владельца окна через 
this.Owner.Show() 
и хочу сделать обработку события показа, чтобы в окне, которое открылось, вызвался метод и выполнил, к примеру, обновление данных в текстовых полях окна. Как обработать это событие в самом владельце?
Дело в том, что мне нужно из главного вызывать дочерние окна и в зависимости от того, что я нажму в открытом окне (Сохранить / Вернуться назад) изменять значения счетчика на главном окне (в первом варианте ++, во втором не менять) и при закрытии Close() дочернего и показе Show() главного окна, обновлять на нем счетчик в текстовом блоке.

Comment: Методы перегружать пробовали `OnShow`, `OnLoad`, `OnClose`? Не уверен что есть метод `OnShow`, но `OnLoad` или `OnLoaded` точно есть.

Comment: Эээ, используйте привязки, такого вопроса у вас не возникнет тогда вообще

Comment: `WPF != WinForms` запомните это раз и на всегда! WPF это привязки, другой совершенно подход к разработки приложения. Вот откройте свой XAML код и выкинете из него все x:Name теги. Запустится? Я думаю, что нет, а должно. Почему не запустилось? Да потому, что вы не работаете с привязками!

Comment: Вот у меня есть переменная int, которую я меняю и есть TextBlock, в   котором я хочу показывать её, как мне забиндить это в коде?

Comment: @Alex 1. Создаете публичное свойство (не поле!) `public int MyValue {get;set}` 2. Привязываете к окну место, где поместили это свойство через DataContext, если это тоже окно (MainWindow), то `DataContext = this;`, если другой класс - не забудьте инициализировать. Ну и 3. - в Xaml задаете привязку `<TextBlock Content = "{Binding MyValue}" />`. Все, вы успешно привязались! Если хотите видеть изменения на форме, если ваше свойство изменилось (из кода), то надо еще реализовать INPC.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И свойство MyValue менять, к примеру так: MyValue = counter; и из-за реализации INPC оно будет обновлять текстблок?

Comment: @Alex Я вот про вас уже забыл, хорошо что листал вопросы заново. Не забывайте оповещать пользователя (добавляя @ с ником). Ну а так да, все будет работать как надо. Вы можете полазить у меня к примеру по ответам, там уже много полезных собралось по MVVM, WPF и Binding, ну или почитайте что нибудь про это все, там легко, главное понять суть и как все устроено ;-)